# How many "co-" topologies are out there?

Tags: general-topology, definition

So far I have learned about $\tau_{co-finite}$ and $\tau_{co-countable}$

Are there any other co-related topologies like...$\tau_{co-infinite}$?

In general, what is the condition we need to have a co-topology?

Comment: What counts as a "co-topology" exactly?  Every topology can be described as consisting of the complements of its closed sets...

Comment: @EricWofsey my line of questioning is similar to the response given by mihail. Is that is there a general condition on which a co-topology is a topology

Comment: There can't be a "co-infinite" topology if you mean to define as open those sets whose cardinality is strictly infinite. Choose a set $A$ so that both $|A|$ and $|X \setminus A|$ are infinite. Both $A$ and $X \setminus A$ are "open" in the "co-infinite topology", yet their union has empty complement, so it is not open. (If you want to declare $X$ to be open by fiat, then consider $A \setminus \{x\}$ and $X \setminus A$ instead.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\mathcal{C}$ is any collection of subsets of a set $X$, you could try to define a "co-$\mathcal{C}$" topology on $X$ whose open sets are exactly the complements of elements of $\mathcal{C}$.  This actually is a topology iff $\mathcal{C}$ satisfies the [axioms for closed sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Closed_sets_definition) (which are just "complemented" versions of the axioms for open sets): $\mathcal{C}$ must be closed under arbitrary intersections and finite unions.

Comment: you are right! good job

Answer (score 3):

Mikhail's answer has the right idea. Here's how to do it rigorously:

> **Definition.** Let $X$ denote a set and $\kappa$ denote a cardinal number. Then $\tau(X,\kappa)$ is the collection of all subsets $A$ of $X$ such that $|A| < \kappa$ or $A = X$.
>
> **Proposition.** If $\kappa \geq \aleph_0$, then $\tau(X,\kappa)$ satisfies the closed-set axioms for a topology on $X$.

For instance, $\tau(X,\aleph_0)$ is the cofinite topology, and $\tau(X,\aleph_1)$ is the co-countable topology.

As there are infinitely many different cardinal numbers, we can make infinitely many different such spaces. We do "need" (to get something interesting) that $|X| \ge \kappa$, or else $\tau(X,\kappa)$ is just the discrete topology. In that case, for different $\kappa$ and $X$ or $X$ of different size, we get non-homeomorphic spaces, and all these spaces are $T_1$ but not $T_2$. And for all $\kappa \ge \aleph_1$ they have no convergent subsequences except the trivial ones that are eventually constant.

Comment: "Infinitely many different cardinal numbers" is a bit of an understatement.

Answer (score 1):

You can define $\tau_{co-\sigma}$. Where $\sigma$ is any infinite cardinality. Define open sets as any subset which has complements with cardinality strictly less than $\sigma$. Check that it is indeed a topology!

Your examples are special cases, where $\sigma$ is countable set and continuum set respectively, if you assume continuum hypothesis.

Comment: thank you, do you have a link to where this result is obtained?

Comment: @goblin thank you! I'll add that in the proof.

Comment: sorry, there is no any links. This is my own answer. Do you need me to write down more explicit proof?

Comment: thank you all for pointing out to the mistakes

Comment: @Mihail you can just use $\aleph_1$ regardless of the continuum hypothesis.